# I am making a table and I have an error of Sql data base

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE data (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  dish VARCHAR(255),
  position INT(3),
  price INT(4),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I am getting an error when I enter this above code:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   dish VARCHAR(255),
>   position INT(3),
> pric' at line 2

Comment: The script itself is correct. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4b1076b80704cd02bf5474fe631b52fa). Test the symbol immediately before `id` - maybe there is some illegal non-printable symbol there? try to re-type the whole query "by hands".

Comment: [Works for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=f29f86ccbb242c90cbe14eb11fadbbee). Check for any odd invisible characters. Or do you have a statement before that, that isn't terminated by a semicolon?

Comment: If the above comments were true, then I think copy-pasting this text into a CLI would result in the same error; it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has its own list of **reserved words**. These words are used for specific purposes or to perform specific functions within the MySQL engine. If you attempting to use one of these reserved words, you will receive the **1064 error**.

Please try using below query

CREATE TABLE `data` (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
dish VARCHAR(255),
position INT(3),
price INT(4),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);